# Oracle sql sort greater date first, based on 2 date column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which contains 2 columns CREATION_DATE AND CHANGE_DATE. I am looking for a way to sort data based on date which is greater.

May be like :

```
select * from table order by compare(CREATION_DATE ,CHANGE_DATE) desc;
```

the compare(CREATION_DATE ,CHANGE_DATE) function suppose to return greater date between both columns.

I have search a lot and tried various combination with date function and NULLS FIST, LAST but not use.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `order by coalesce(CHANGE_DATE, CREATION_DATE) desc`, since I assume change date can never be before creation date.

Comment: @jarlh your comment was helpful and solved my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If neither date is `NULL`, then you can use:

```
order by greatest(creation_date, change_date) desc
```

Unfortunately, `greatest()` returns `NULL` if *any* value is `NULL`.

If `change_date` is either `NULL` or bigger than `creation_date`, then you can use `coalesce()`:

```
order by coalesce(change_date, creation_date)
```

This situation makes sense to me -- changing something before it is created is unusual.

If `change_date` can be `NULL` and can also be less than `creation_date`, then you need to be more careful.  You need to replace by a value.  Presumably, `creation_date` would not be `NULL` and you can use `coalesce()`:

```
order by greatest(creation_date, coalesce(change_date, creation_date)) desc
```

Or a `case` expression:

```
order by (case when change_date > creation_date then change_date
               else creation_date
          end)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `compare`, but - use `greatest`.

```
order by greatest(creation_date, change_date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? You can order by Boolean expressions ...

```
WITH
indata(comp,cr_dt,chg_dt) AS (
          SELECT 'same'      ,'2021-02-15', '2021-02-15' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'cr_bigger' ,'2021-02-16', '2021-02-15' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'chg_bigger','2021-02-15', '2021-02-16' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'cr_bigger' ,'2021-02-26', '2021-02-25' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'chg_bigger','2021-02-25', '2021-02-26' FROM dual
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN cr_dt > chg_dt
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS cr_is_greater
, comp
, cr_dt
, chg_dt
FROM indata
ORDER BY 1 DESC
;
 cr_is_greater |    comp    |   cr_dt    |   chg_dt
---------------+------------+------------+------------
             1 | cr_bigger  | 2021-02-16 | 2021-02-15
             1 | cr_bigger  | 2021-02-26 | 2021-02-25
             0 | same       | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-15
             0 | chg_bigger | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-16
             0 | chg_bigger | 2021-02-25 | 2021-02-26
```

Comment: I don't think this was meant. And I don't think this works in Oracle, because in Oracle SQL there is no boolean data type unfortunately. Apart from this, the `WITH` clause would need `FROM dual`, as in Oracle you must always select *from* something.